# Facebook App Invites opens SafariViewController instead of Native app

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement the [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites) feature from Facebook and I'd like to have my users redirected to the Native Facebook app (if installed on the user's device).

However, event though the Facebook Native app is installed on the device it is never opened, the 'Invite Dialog' is always opened in a `SafariViewController` instead (see attached image below). This is undesired because most of the time the user isn't logged in the Safari and would give up completing the "invite" task.

**Here are SDK versions I'm using to build the app:**

- iOS: 9.0
- Facebook iOS SDK: 4.6.0
- Facebook Unity SDK: 7.1.0

I've read the [Preparing Your Apps for iOS9](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) and already populated my Info.plist with all possible URL schemes:

`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string></string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
</array>`

Nonetheless, the `SafariViewController` is always opened instead the Facebook Native App.

**How can I have my app users to use the 'App Invite' dialog using the Native Facebook app?**

[image: App Invite in SafariViewController]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like this was designed by Facebook, apparently Facebook choses to use SafariViewController to avoid asking for permission to switch app several times. You can check the FAQ [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

> FAQ
>
> Why do I see a ' wants to open Facebook' alert dialog when invoking a
>   dialog?
>
> In iOS 9, the app switches can prompt the user with a confirmation
>   dialog. The SDK will try to minimize the frequency of this by choosing
>   the best dialog available (such as SafariViewController), but this is
>   by design in iOS 9.

Comment: is it the same on ios10 ?

Comment: Yes, it is an iOS 9 or newer thing

Comment: @FranciscoMedina does this mean that since iOS 9 it's not possible to use the native app for login anymore? i.e a webview will always be used.

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues I haven't keep up with Facebook sdk, but yes, the sdk manages how the login happens, there is no control for the developer on how the login is handled